# Using u128 without sacrificing alignment 8

Tags: anchor, deserialization

We have a struct like:

```
#[account(zero_copy)]
#[repr(C)]
pub struct SomeStruct {
    pub authority: Pubkey,
    pub some_value: u128,
    pub another_value: u64,
// etc...
}
```

This struct has alignment 16 because of the use of u128, which causes issues with some platforms, such as the Rust-based anchor client. We have lots of problems with alignment 16 generally, while 8 is universal. We can fix this by using:

```
#[account(zero_copy)]
#[repr(C)]
pub struct SomeStruct {
    pub authority: Pubkey,
    pub some_value: [u8; 16],
    pub another_value: u64,
// etc...
}
impl SomeStruct {
    pub fn some_value_u128(&self) -> u128 {
        bytemuck::cast_slice(&self.some_value)[0]
    }
}
```

Now it aligns 8, which is compatible with everything, and we can still update the value with `some_struct.some_value = new_value.to_ne_bytes();` Great. The only problem is that the idl now generates an array like:

```
  "type": {
    "array": {
      "len": 16,
      "type": "u8"
    }
  }
```

i.e. a number[], instead of a BN. We can easily make it back into a BN with: `new anchor.BN(someStruct.someValue, undefined, "le"),`, so it is easily convertible, but this is annoying for anyone integrating on top of our idl.

How can we force the IDL to treat the `[u8; 16]` slice as a BN for deserialization purposes, so it can accessed as a BN like `let a: BN = someStruct.someValue` on the TS side without the additional conversion? Ultimately it *is* a BN, so this should be possible.

Manually editing the IDL to make the type a BN just returns the raw bytes.

Comment: This sounds like a general Rust question most appropriately asked in a Rust language help forum. The Rust Discord is very helpful for questions like these.

Comment: The Rust side of this is fine, using the u8 slice allows you to keep alignment 8. What we need is a way to have this slice to serialize and deserialize as a simple u128 BN when Anchor creates the idl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `[u8; 16]` works for you, then you can trick Anchor into treating it as a `u128` by creating a custom type with the same name, `"u128"`. To not pollute the outer scope, you declare it in a module. Like so:

```
mod custom_scope {

    use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

    #[derive(Copy, Clone, bytemuck::Zeroable, bytemuck::Pod, Debug)]
    #[repr(C)]
    pub struct u128(pub [u8; 16]);

    impl u128 {
        pub fn as_u128(&self) -> core::primitive::u128 {
            core::primitive::u128::from_le_bytes(self.0)
        }
    }

    #[account(zero_copy)]
    #[repr(C)]
    pub struct SomeStruct {
        pub authority: Pubkey,
        pub some_value: u128, // anchor will think this `u128` is a primitive and not a custom type
        pub data: u64,
    }
}
```

It is key to also declare `SomeStruct` in the same scope so that we can do `pub some_value: u128` because this is what tricks Anchor into treating it as a regular `u128` and not a custom type.

And now, when your client sends data as `u128` you can simply transform it into the type the account expects, with `custom_scope::u128(some_value.to_le_bytes())`.

Or if you want your `my_account.some_value` to act as a `u128`, you can simply do `my_account.some_value.as_u128()`.

Here's the demo: https://beta.solpg.io/65184223fb53fa325bfd0bc9

Check the test file and notice it treats the `someValue` field in the account as `BN` without additional conversion. This works because in the account, the byte layout of `custom_scope::u128` and `u128` is the same so the client can treat it as a simple `u128`.

And in the IDL that the above link generates during build, it will show

```
{
    "name": "someValue",
    "type": "u128"
}
```